# Searching for a string in multiple fields in a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

There's lots of examples of complex systems to find a string in all the columns in a table or DB. Mine has to look for a string in 10 fields out of about 100 in a particular table, so these solutions are too complex.

Right now I do the dumb thing:

```
SELECT * FROM sometbl WHERE FIELD0 LIKE 'zap' OR FIELD1 LIKE 'zap'...
```

But this results in really nasty-to-read SQL. So then I thought...

```
SELECT * FROM sometbl WHERE '%zap%' LIKE FIELD0+FIELD1+FEILD2...
```

I cannot convince myself this works. For one, is the LIKE bi-directional so that can I put the %'s on the LHS? Or do those %'s have to be on the RHS?

So then I thought...

```
SELECT * FROM sometbl WHERE CHARINDEX('zap',FIELD0+FIELD1+FEILD2...) > 0
```

Can anyone comment on these solutions, and whether I should use any of them?

Comment: Note - there's a risk of false positives with `FIELD0+FIELD1+...` solutions. Example: if FIELD0 = 'pizza' and FIELD1 = 'pizza' and the rest of the fields are empty strings, then the row would match 'zap', though it's not in any one column. Adding a unique separator that you can guarantee would not occur in your data would help. Also - if any of the columns could be `NULL`, and you're using standard `NULL` handling, then any row with one `NULL` column would never match anything (because `FIELD0+FIELD1+...` would be `NULL`). You'd want to handle that, unless the columns are `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using any wild cards then can use `=`

Starting a like with `%` kills the use of an index
Not good

Just stay with

```
SELECT * 
  FROM sometbl 
 WHERE FIELD0 = 'zap' 
    OR FIELD1 = 'zap'
```

Can use variable to only set once
Can use `in`

```
declare @val varchar(200)  = 'message/rfc822'

select sID, mimeType, caseID 
  from docSVsys 
 where mimetype = @val 
    or caseID   = @val;

select sID, mimeType, caseID 
  from docSVsys 
 where @val in (mimetype, caseID)
```